# What is the correct syntax to configure an automatically jenkins build after commit a svn project?

Tags: svn, jenkins

I mean what is the correct syntax for example for

every 1 Hour

every 24 Hour

every week (i mean only one build per week)

I know the syntax for 1 minute:

```
* /1 * * * *
```

Thanks for help !

Greetz
Marwief

Answer (score 1):

Since Jenkins uses standard cron syntax with a couple of enhancements, you have too many entries in your cron string.  Here are some examples:

Every minute:

---

Every 1 hour at 5 minutes past:

5 * * * *

Every 24 hours at 7:05:

5 7 * * *

Once per week on Monday at 7:05:

5 7 * * 1

Click the ? icon next to the schedule field in the Jenkins UI for more examples, or type "man cron" on a Linux system.